# Why does console.log(new Map<String, Number>([])) log true, true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What exactly is causing this TypeScript-like expression to log `true, true` in JavaScript?

```js
console.log(new Map<String, Number>([]))
```

Comment: I get `Map(0) {}`, not `true, true` - [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowJs=true&target=6#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUZYHcAEBZAhgA4A8AygC4BOAlmMgDTYByArgLYBGslAfKgNoBdAJTCA3EA)

Comment: I'm using chrome version 92.0.4515.159, checking the console shows `Map(0) {}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you format it differently, you can see that this might look like TS, but it's just JavaScript. Coincidentally, the angle brackets and the comma match perfectly with the syntax for the two arguments of console.log, where each is a comparison, less than and greater than. What is being compared is:

```
new Map < String // true
Number > [] // true
```

Written out in a way that makes this more obvious:

```
console.log(new Map < String, Number > ([]))
```

If you meant to write this in a TS file where it might get interpreted (as you may have intended) as a type generic, then you are probably looking for different types: `string` and `number`, rather than the `String` and `Number` constructors that you used in the example.

Comment: Haha, awesome, that is pretty hilarious. I thought for a second, wow, Javascript has type notation now?